# Как инициализировать параметры экземпляра класса 2 из класса 1?

Tags: java

Решаю задачу по теме классов и конструкторов.
Есть класс Main, в нем реализован метод  public static void main, который через Scanner принимает значения переменных. Есть класс Line, который принимает эти переменные.
Вопрос, почему в методе inter класса Line не получается инициализировать и использовать эти переменные? Как это сделать ?
Спасибо.

```
public class Main {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int k1 = scanner.nextInt();
        int b1 = scanner.nextInt();
        int k2 = scanner.nextInt();
        int b2 = scanner.nextInt();
        Line line1 = new Line(k1,b1); //создаем экземпляр класса и передаем в него нашу переменную
        Line line2 = new Line(k2,b2);
        System.out.println("result is " + line1.inter(line2));
    }
}
```

```
    public class Line {
    public Line(int kk, int bb) {
        System.out.println(kk+" "+bb);
    }
    public Point inter(Line other) {
       // if(k1 == k2){System.out.println("0");}
      //  int x = (b1 - b2) / (k2 - k1);
       // int y = k1 * x + b1;
 return х,y; }
}
```

```
public class Point {
    private final int x;
    private final int y;
    public Point(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("(%d;%d)", x, y);
    }
}
```

Comment: Потому что k1 и k2 в одном файле не имеют ни малейшего отношения к k1 и k2 в другом файле.

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понял, что именно должно получиться в результате. У вас парочка явных ошибок есть. Гляньте, быть может поможет...

```
    public class Line {

    public static int k1;
    public static int k2;

    public Line(int kk, int bb) {
        this.k1 = kk;
        this.k2 = bb;

        System.out.println(kk + " " + bb);
    }

    public Point inter(Line other) {

        Point x = new Point(k1, k2);
        return x;
    }
}
```

Comment: Программа должна считать пересекаются ли отрезки с координатами k1-b1 и k2-b2